# Load 8 images per category in portfolio

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress 4.4.2 with 'Jupiter' theme.

Here is link of my theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/jupiter-multipurpose-responsive-theme/full_screen_preview/5177775

I have a portfolio page in which I have set 'load more' option. There are few categories in it and also have category “ALL” which is showing all category images. By default I am showing 8 images. The default tab to be selected on page load is “ALL”. When I am clicking on any category at that time it is only showing images which are loaded in ALL. But I want to show minimum 8 images to be loaded in all category with minimum load on page.

So is there any way to do this in Jupiter theme or any patch to do this?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using free theme? or free plugin for portfolio. if then it may happened. because in free version there is limited service only. if you're using paid version then you can contact with support team

Comment: You should check Theme Options, Also Read Theme Documentation. Also Check that you assign category to images in portfolio.